# Selenium RC is not opening url given in my code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-firefoxdriver

The RC launches the firefox browser but it tries to open the following link
"chrome://src/content/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=94c0e90deec8470ab358718255d27575&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&debugMode=false&driverUrl=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/"

instead of "https://www.facebook.com/"

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DemoClass {
     private Selenium selenium;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "https://www.facebook.com/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void Assignment1() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("id=email"));
        assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("id=pass"));
        selenium.type("id=email", "devranipankaj163@gmail.com");
            selenium.type("id=pass", "demo@123");
        assertEquals("devranipankaj163@gmail.com", selenium.getValue("id=email"));
        selenium.click("id=u_0_n");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
     }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Selenium RC as it is heavily outdated and not maintained anymore.

You should be using `Selenium Webdriver` with the latest version being 3.1.0 for Java. If you want to run your tests against Firefox you will also need `Geckodriver`.

[Here is a good blog post](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3) that explains the setup and other basics of Selenium 3 and Geckodriver.